# How do I add Javascript to my HTML and CSS tic tac toe game?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, tic-tac-toe

This is my HTML and CSS. I have no embedded Javascript. I do however reference a Javascript file. What is the simplest Javascript to just have an `X` and 'O' appear when I click on a box?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="gameboard">

                <div class="Row1">
                    <div id="cell1"></div>
                    <div id="cell2"></div>
                    <div id="cell3"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="Row2">
                    <div id="cell4"></div>
                    <div id="cell5"></div>
                    <div id="cell6"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="Row3">
                    <div id="cell7"></div>
                    <div id="cell8"></div>
                    <div id="cell9"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="button">

            <button>New Game</button>
            <button>End Game</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}


body {
    background-image: url("http://www.staceybess.com/gfx/bg-chalkboard.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}


#chalk {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}


.gameboard {
    width: 328px;
    height:318px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 75px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 330px;
    margin:0 auto;

}

.button {

     background-color:white;
     width: 160px;
     margin:0 auto;
}

button {
    float: left;
}

.row1, .row2, .row3 {
    clear:both;

}

#cell1,#cell2,#cell4,#cell5 {
    border-right: 8px solid white;
    border-bottom: 8px solid white;
    border-style: eraser;
}

#cell3,#cell6{
    border-bottom: 8px solid white;
}

#cell7 {
    border-right: 8px solid white;
}

#cell9 {
    border-left: 8px solid white;
}

#cell1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell3 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell4 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell5 {
width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell6 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell7 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell8 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

#cell9 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add Javascript, not Java. Although the name is similar, those are completely different programming languages.

Comment: JAVA != JAAAVAAASSCCRIPPPTPTPTTPTPTPTPTPEH, READ TAG DISCRIPTION

Comment: We do not code for you; by the way, change all classes to the same class, unless you're planning to use **id.**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use different class for each row if not needed.
Use row and cell everywhere.

Include jquery.js via the link in head.

Then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gameboard").find(".cell").click(function(){
        console.log("Clicked");
    });
});
```

Ok now it say 'clicked'.

Let's make adding 'X' or 'O'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tour = 0;
    $(".gameboard").find(".cell").click(function(){
        if(tour%2==0){
            $(this).text("O");
        } else {
            $(this).text("X");
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

Now we must not override previous value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tour = 0;
    $(".gameboard").find(".cell").click(function(){
        if($this.text() != ""){ return; }
        if(tour%2==0){
            $(this).text("O");
        } else {
            $(this).text("X");
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: My girlfriend wait for me to watch a tv show, please someone continue :p